# If $x$ and $y$ are in this given sequence, can $2^x+2^y+1$ be prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The sequence:

$3, 11, 13, 17, 19, 29, 37, 41, 53, 59, 61, 67, 83, 97, 101, 107, 113, 131, 137, 139, 149, 163, 173, 179, 181, 193, 197, 211, 227, 257, 269, 281, 293, 313, 317, 347, 349, 353, 373, 379, 389, 401, 409, 419, 421, 443, 449, 461, 467, 491, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 577, 587, 593, 613, 617, 619, 653, 659, 661, 677, 701, 709, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 821, 827, 829, 853, 857, 859, 877, 883, 907, 929$...

$n = 2^x + 2^y + 1$

$x,y$ in this sequence.

Is there  case that $n$ is prime with this sequence?

Comment: What is that sequence?

Comment: @Ethan, I think the question is, if $x$ and $y$ are in the given sequence, can $2^x+2^y+1$ be prime?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,thanks.

Comment: @Ethan,is 0 in this sequence?

Comment: You're welcome. But you haven't answered my question.

Comment: Sample: 2^3+ 2^13 +1 = 8201 = 59 * 139

Comment: Is it this sequence?  http://oeis.org/A226014

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,that's 3,11,13,17,19,29,37,41...

Comment: @A Walker ,yes,it is.Let's develop this sequence.

Comment: $7396$ distinct tuples $(x,y)$ can be formed with the terms you have given, I would just do a brute force search.

Comment: Why don't you tell us where the sequence came from?

Comment: So, miket, why didn't you tell us what you already knew about the sequence? Don't you think it would help you get an answer, if you had let us in on the secret of A226014?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such pairs do exist, and they are precisely the columns of the following matrix:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
 3 & 3 & 11 & 37 & 53 & 59 & 179 & 179 & 197 & 227 & 353 & 421 & 449 & 467 & 853 \\
 37 & 317 & 17 & 67 & 83 & 797 & 293 & 509 & 227 & 509 & 587 & 787 & 659 & 653 & 907
   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The minimal prime obtained in this way is, by inspection, $2^{11}+2^{17}+1=133121$.

**Edit:** I forgot to check the diagonal!  That adds the single pair $(3,3)$, corresponding to $$2^3+2^3+1=17.$$
This brings us to a total of $16$ solutions.

Comment: Very interesting.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The integer $17$ is prime,

The integer $3$ appears in your sequence,

Also

$2^3+2^3+1=17$

Comment: I suspect OP wants $x\ne y$, but it's hard to get any information from that source.

Comment: Thanks! $x$ can be equal to $y$.